How can I increase the horizontal margin between components in PlantUML?
I'm trying to create a UML diagram with PlantUML and I want to increase the horizontal margin between the components. I've tried using the skinparam nodesep setting, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is an example of my code
@startuml Component Diagram

!include https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plantuml-stdlib/C4-PlantUML/master/C4_Component.puml
!include https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plantuml-stdlib/C4-PlantUML/master/C4_Container.puml

skinparam nodesep 200 ' horizontal margin '
skinparam ranksep 100 ' vertical margin '

title Example Workflow

AddElementTag("System", $bgColor="#AEC6CF", $borderColor="#AEC6CF", $legendText="System")
AddElementTag("External", $bgColor="#D3D3D3", $borderColor="#D3D3D3", $legendText="External Service")

System_Boundary(c1, "Example System") { 

    Component(component1, "Component 1", "Description 1")
    Component(component2, "Component 2", "Description 2")
    Component(component3, "Component 3", "Description 3")
    Component(component4, "Component 4", "Description 4")
    Component(component5, "Component 5", "Description 5", $tags="External")
    Component(error_handle, "Error Handling", "Handle errors")

    Component(component6, "Component 6", "Description 6")
    
}

' External interactions
Person(user, "User", "Initiates request")

' Interactions and workflow arrows
Rel(user, component1 , "Action 1")
Rel(component1, component2, "Action 2")
Rel(component2, component3, "Action 3")
Rel(component3, component4, "Action 4")
Rel(component4, component5, "Action 5")

Rel(user, component6, "Action 6")

' Error handling interactions
Rel(component2, error_handle, "Failed action", "If input is invalid")
Rel(error_handle, component1, "Prompt retry", "If retry allowed")

SHOW_LEGEND()

@enduml

I want to increase the horizontal space between the components without changing the layout. How can I achieve this?
I've tried using the skinparam nodesep setting, but it doesn't seem to work.
